# Spring Boot Authorizes User In Rest Client, But Not In Browser (Rest Authorization)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Ok, so when I use my Rest Client (Insomnia). I am able to log into my Spring Server and successfully retrieves data afterwards.

But when I try to use my angularJS Client. I can successfully log in but then when I try to retrieve data, it sends back a 401 error as if it forgot I ever logged in. I am very confused.

You may notice X-AUTH-TOKEN in the code. As of right now, I do not have it setup where it is checking X-AUTH-TOKEN so disregard this and please note that it WORKS in my REST CLIENT but not in the Browser Client.

I even tried to add the same amount of request header information in my REST CLIENT as my browser client, it still retrieves data for it.

Below is my WebSecurityConfig

```
package app.config;

import app.repo.User.CustomUserDetailsService;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import app.security.TokenAuthenticationService;
import app.security.filters.StatelessAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static PasswordEncoder encoder;
    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    private CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

//        http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
//                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        this.userService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", customUserDetailsService);
        return tokenAuthenticationService;
    }
}
```

I also have a CorsFilter

```
package app.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    public CorsFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Why is it that Spring accepts my Spring Requests after logging in, but not my Client Request after logging in.

I check If the user is authenticated via persistent database

```
package app.repo.User;

import app.cache.UserService;
import app.security.UserAuthentication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.*;

@Service
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private final AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker detailsChecker = new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker();
    private final HashMap<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<String, User>();

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        app.repo.User.User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad Credentials");
        }
        userService.setUserInfo(user);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        UserDetails userDetails = buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
//        detailsChecker.check(userDetails);
        return userDetails;

    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(app.repo.User.User user,
                                            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoleName()));
        }

        return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        userMap.put(user.getUsername(), user);
    }
}
```

## Here is my Request Headers for Browser LOGIN

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

## Here are response headers for browser LOGIN

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:88
Date:Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:22:39 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=966F22A08A6D30E73FDC0DF40749C5C2; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

## Here are Request Headers For Retrieving Data in browser

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

## response headers for retrieving data Data in Browser

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:25:03 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

For my Rest Client. The Response Headers are the Same. For The Request headers for Rest Client, It doesnt have any to show. But I tried adding the exact same headers to the Rest Client and it still works.

Here is my angularjs call

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: loginUrl
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  var resp = response;
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.siteUrl+'/get-all-games'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var resp = response;
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    var resp = response;
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  var resp = response;
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

I setup my $http call to do a call to retrieve data immediately after success of login... It still returns a 401 error even though I successfully logged in.

Comment: I've added the Request and Response headers for both Logging in and retrieving the data. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am stepping through the code and it looks like it still considers my client to be anonymous despite logging in. Ive added my $http call as well. I set it up where it immediately calls data after a succesful log in. Still returns a 401

Comment: So I guess my Client Rest Saves this automatically. I wish My REST client showed me my request headers. I probably would of figured it out. I will check it out though. thanks

Comment: I'd also make sure you are persisting your authentication in the session?  Often a REST client will make do with basic authentication (I see you do enable that) without persistence (thus sending the username/password in a basic authentication header with every request).  If you have no persistence setup then your login form will authenticate when sent down but not on future requests.  I don't see a SecurityContextPersistenceFilter in your code snippets.

Comment: Are you using namespace configuration then?  Also, you can use a proxy like fiddler to see your rest headers.

Comment: numerical25 : How did you solved it? I have a similar issue. My SecurityContextHolder returns username as NULL, if I make a call with a RestClient but works fine if I make the api call directly using Postman. @Pace : Would appreciate your help as well.

Answer (score 0):

The credential info,  which is cookie/session id in this case, should be carried with your request for retrieving data in browser.
The angular client can be configured like the following to do that.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```